# D3.js draw diamonds and connecting links in a decision tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on the below layout ( decision tree) using D3 where I need to draw diamond shapes for the nodes that are "decisions" in a flow chart and rest of the nodes are actions ( rectangles).

Logically, all the nodes that have children are diamond shapes. Below is a UX Visualisation.

[image]

I've come up with a jsfiddle for the top to bottom D3 chart here : https://jsfiddle.net/p6vrmnu0/3/

But all the svg elements are currently rectangles and all the lines are now connected by "curved" links, I would like svgs to be diamonds for "decision" nodes and  the links to be similar to the above image originating from the diamond's two corners and ending at at the top of the rhombus if the next is decision or top of rectangle if the next is an action.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var emptyDecisionBox = {
  "name": "newDecision",
  "id": "newId",
  "value": "notSure",
  "condition": "true",
};

var selectedNode;


var root = {
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "analytics",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a+b",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distinction",
        "type": "action",
        "condition": "true",
        "value": "5",
      }, {
        "name": "nonDistinction",
        "type": "action",
        "condition": "false",
        "value": "4"
      }],
    },
    {
      "name": "division",
      "type": "action",
      "value": "a-b",
      "children": [],
    }
  ]
};

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  rectW = 60,
  rectH = 30;

var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000)
  .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([350, 20]);

// new part
var plusButton = svg
  .append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("CLICKED");
  });

plusButton
  .append('rect')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-8, -8)') // center the button inside the `g`
  .attr('width', 16)
  .attr('height', 16)
  .attr('rx', 2);

plusButton
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M-6 0 H6 M0 -6 V6');

var rectangleShape = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    removeAllButtonElements();
  })

rectangleShape
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');


var diamondImage = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addElement(selectedNode);
    console.log("Clicked on Diamond");
    console.log("set hide to true");
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImage
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 20 0 40 20 20 40 0 20 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


var rectangleShapeFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("rectangle clicked");
    removeAllButtonElements();
  })

rectangleShapeFalse
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');

var diamondImageFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("Clicked on Diamond");
    console.log("set hide to true");
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImageFalse
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 20 0 40 20 20 40 0 20 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


function removeAllButtonElements() {
  plusButton.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImage.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShape.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImageFalse.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShapeFalse.classed('hide', true);
}

// new part ends. 

root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

/* root.children.forEach(collapse); */
update(root);

d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  /*   nodeEnter.append('path').attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type( function(d) { return "circle" }) );
   */

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
    //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);

  nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .on('mouseenter', function(d, i) {
      // Use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box to
      // calculate the center of the path
      var bbox = this.getBBox();
      var x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2,
        y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
      plusButton
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
        .classed('hide', false);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(d, i) {
      plusButton
        .classed('hide', true);
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
/* function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
} */


function click(d) {
  console.log(d);
  selectedNode = d;
  /*     if(d.children && d.children.length < 1){
              return;
        } */
  var x = d.x;
  var y = d.y + 40;
  /*       plusButton
                 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
          .classed('hide', false);
           
         plusButton
                 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
          .classed('hide', false); */

  var m = d.x + 50;
  var h = d.y + 20;

  diamondImage
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);

  var m = d.x + 60;
  var h = d.y - 10;

  rectangleShape
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);

  var m = d.x - 40;
  var h = d.y + 20;

  diamondImageFalse
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);

  var m = d.x - 40;
  var h = d.y - 10;

  rectangleShapeFalse
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);
}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function addElement(d) {
  console.log(d);

  d.children = [];
  d.children.push(emptyDecisionBox);
  update(root);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button>path {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}

.button>rect {
  fill: #ddd;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 8px;
}

.scale {
  /* transform: scale(0.4); */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-diagram"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the line shape, I recommend to just write a shape function yourself. I wrote one that goes horizontal, then makes a small curve, then goes down. It doesn't take the width of the shape into account, but that shouldn't matter, since it's behind the box after all.

For the box shapes, I'd do something similar. Instead of using `rects`, use a `path`, and write the shape of the path using an if statement. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) is always a very valuable resource.

Just to get you started:

```js
function drawDiamond(centroid) {
  // Start at the top
  var result = 'M' + centroid.x + ',' + (centroid.y - rectH / 2);

  // Go right
  result += 'L' + (centroid.x + rectW / 2) + ',' + centroid.y;

  // Bottom
  result += 'L' + centroid.x + ',' + (centroid.y + rectH / 2);

  // Left
  result += 'L' + (centroid.x - rectW / 2) + ',' + centroid.y;

  // Close the shape
  result += 'Z';

  return result;
}

function drawRect(centroid) {
  // Start at the top left
  var result = 'M' + (centroid.x - rectW / 2) + ',' + (centroid.y - rectH / 2);

  // Go right
  result += 'h' + rectW;

  // Go down
  result += 'v' + rectH;

  // Left
  result += 'h-' + rectW;

  // Close the shape
  result += 'Z';

  return result;
}
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var emptyDecisionBox = {
  "name": "newDecision",
  "id": "newId",
  "value": "notSure",
  "condition": "true",
};

var selectedNode;


var root = {
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "analytics",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a+b",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distinction",
        "type": "action",
        "condition": "true",
        "value": "5",
      }, {
        "name": "nonDistinction",
        "type": "action",
        "condition": "false",
        "value": "4"
      }],
    },
    {
      "name": "division",
      "type": "action",
      "value": "a-b",
      "children": [],
    }
  ]
};

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  rectW = 60,
  rectH = 30;

var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
var linkFunc = function(d) {
  var source = {
    x: d.source.x,
    y: d.source.y + (rectH / 2)
  };
  var target = {
    x: d.target.x + (rectW / 2),
    y: d.target.y
  };

  // This is where the line bends
  var inflection = {
    x: target.x,
    y: source.y
  };
  var radius = 5;

  var result = "M" + source.x + ',' + source.y;
  
  if (source.x < target.x) {
    // Child is to the right of the parent
    result += ' H' + (inflection.x - radius);
  } else {
    result += ' H' + (inflection.x + radius);
  }

  // Curve the line at the bend slightly
  result += ' Q' + inflection.x + ',' + inflection.y + ' ' + inflection.x + ',' + (inflection.y + radius);

  result += 'V' + target.y;
  return result;
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000)
  .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([350, 20]);

// new part
var plusButton = svg
  .append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("CLICKED");
  });

plusButton
  .append('rect')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-8, -8)') // center the button inside the `g`
  .attr('width', 16)
  .attr('height', 16)
  .attr('rx', 2);

plusButton
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M-6 0 H6 M0 -6 V6');

var rectangleShape = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    removeAllButtonElements();
  })

rectangleShape
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');


var diamondImage = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addElement(selectedNode);
    console.log("Clicked on Diamond");
    console.log("set hide to true");
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImage
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 20 0 40 20 20 40 0 20 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


var rectangleShapeFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("rectangle clicked");
    removeAllButtonElements();
  })

rectangleShapeFalse
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');

var diamondImageFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("Clicked on Diamond");
    console.log("set hide to true");
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImageFalse
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 20 0 40 20 20 40 0 20 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


function removeAllButtonElements() {
  plusButton.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImage.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShape.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImageFalse.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShapeFalse.classed('hide', true);
}

// new part ends. 

root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

/* root.children.forEach(collapse); */
update(root);

d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  /*   nodeEnter.append('path').attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type( function(d) { return "circle" }) );
   */

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
    //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);

  nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("d", linkFunc)
    .on('mouseenter', function(d, i) {
      // Use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box to
      // calculate the center of the path
      var bbox = this.getBBox();
      var x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2,
        y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
      plusButton
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
        .classed('hide', false);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(d, i) {
      plusButton
        .classed('hide', true);
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", linkFunc);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", linkFunc)
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}


function click(d) {
  console.log(d);
  selectedNode = d;
  var x = d.x;
  var y = d.y + 40;

  var m = d.x + 50;
  var h = d.y + 20;

  diamondImage
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);

  var m = d.x + 60;
  var h = d.y - 10;

  rectangleShape
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);

  var m = d.x - 40;
  var h = d.y + 20;

  diamondImageFalse
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);

  var m = d.x - 40;
  var h = d.y - 10;

  rectangleShapeFalse
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m + ', ' + h + ')')
    .classed('hide', false);
}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function addElement(d) {
  console.log(d);

  d.children = [];
  d.children.push(emptyDecisionBox);
  update(root);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button>path {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}

.button>rect {
  fill: #ddd;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 8px;
}

.scale {
  /* transform: scale(0.4); */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-diagram"></div>
```

Now, there are some problems with your code in general.
You set the attributes of items you're going to delete, or items that have already been set. Remember that *every* node that is on the page has already been entered once, so when you set their width/height/stroke, there is no reason to ever set it again, unless it changes. Similarly, there is *no* reason to use `nodeUpdate.select('rect')` and then set all the values all over again, just remove that code, it does nothing and leads to clutter.

You also don't select by class, but by tag. That will give you problems as soon as you start with paths. Use classes instead!

Comment: not sure why, but all the comments are deleted. You gave me some valuable info in those comments. Wanted to reference them. I am close to my implementation but  am facing an issue, I did not draw the images around the centroid, instead had a fixed diamond/rect path returned. I was able to achieve the transition fine, but the old links and paths are not getting removed. I asked a question here - if you are interested to take a look at it :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818382/d3-js-old-links-not-getting-deleted-after-adding-a-new-node-and-trasitioning  .

Comment: Ah yes, comments are meant to be temporary, sorry about that. I just answered your question, so hopefully it's fine